# maximal and usual subgroups

Tags: group-theory, maximal-subgroup

Can a group $G$ have a maximal subgroup and at the same time have a subgroup $H$ which is not contained in a maximal subgroup?

Comment: For finite groups, every subgroup is contained in a maximal one, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667938/every-subgroup-of-a-finite-group-is-contained-in-a-maximal-subgroup/667952). A Prüfer group $P$ has no maximal subgroups, so one can consider $P\times C_2$, see Derek's answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $H$ be a group with no maximal subgroups ($H = ({\mathbb Q},+)$ for example), $K = C_2$, and let $G = H \times K$. Then $G$ has the maximal subgroup $H$, but the subgroup $K$ of $G$ is not contained in a maximal subgroup.

Comment: Thank you very much!